# Estoy haciendo el siguiente ejemplo y no sé que está fallando

Tags: javascript, array, bucle-for, números-enteros

La función llamada 'menorMayor' recibe como argumento un arreglo de números llamado 'numeros' y debe devolver un arreglo que contenga el menor número del arreglo 'numeros' en la posición cero y el mayor número del arreglo 'numeros' en la posición 1.
Ej:
`menorMayor([4, 6, 1, 7, 15])` debe retornar `[1, 15]`
ya que 1 es el número más chico (menor) dentro del arreglo `[4, 6, 1, 7, 15]`
y 15 es el número más grande (mayor) dentro del arreglo `[4, 6, 1, 7, 15]`

Esto es lo que hice, no sé que estoy haciendo mal

```js
function menorMayor(numeros) {
  let min = numeros[0];

  for (var i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
    if (numeros[i] < min) {
      min = numeros[i];
    }
  }
  let max = numeros[0];
  for (var i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
    if (numeros[i] > max) {
      max = numeros[i];
    }
  }
  return max, min;
}

console.log(menorMayor([4, 6, 1, 7, 15]));
```

Comment: No sé qué es lo que está fallando, pero lo que devuelves no es un `array`. Para que sea un array deberías poner `return [min, max];`

Comment: Como añadido a lo que dijo @Sokkian no puedes retornar dos valores, un `return` te permite solo retornar 1

Comment: Obviamente ese return tira un error no? que error tira?

Comment: No da error, solo no ejecuta el código :c

Comment: @gbianchi Investigando descubrí que la coma por si sola es un [operador](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) y resuelve siempre el último elemento. Entonces no hay error. *The more you learn*

Comment: @FranAcuna interesante!!! tambien inentendible que hace :p

Comment: Gracias por el dato, @FranAcuna, va a ser bueno realizar pruebas para ver el comportamiento y probable utilidad en diferentes casos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Como ya te dijo @Riven en comentarios, no puedes devolver 2 valores y `return max, min;` <strike>podría generar error de sintaxis</strike> devuelve solo el último valor (gracias por la aclaración @FranAcuna).

Debes corregir encerrando ambos valores entre corchetes para que sea un arreglo válido `return [max, min];`. Pero no están en el orden correcto de acuerdo al enunciado:

> debe devolver un arreglo que contenga el menor número del arreglo 'numeros' en la posición cero y el mayor número del arreglo 'numeros' en la posición 1

No es necesario usar ciclos para obtener los elementos, puedes hacer uso de funciones matemáticas como [Math.min()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) para obtener el menor y [Math.max()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) para el máximo.

El "único detalle" es que no puedes enviar el arreglo `numeros` como parámetro, tienes que [desestructurarlo](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) para que todos los elementos se tomen como parámetros individuales.

```js
function menorMayor(numeros) {
    return [Math.min(...numeros), Math.max(...numeros)];
}

console.log(menorMayor([4, 6, 1, 7, 15]));
```

**Importante:** La desestructuración es una característica de introducida a partir de [ECMAScript 6](http://es6-features.org/#Constants). No olvides consultar la [tabla de compatibilidad](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#compatibilidad_del_navegador) para saber en qué navegadores está disponible.

Comment: Dios, nunca pensé en la posibilidad de hacerlo sin un loop, muchas gracias!

Comment: @SergioJáureguiÁngel internamente, el lenguaje esta haciendo un loop.. solo que vos no lo escribiste.. llamaste a una funcion que lo hace.. esto solo como aclaracion de que el codigo no es magico...

Comment: @gbianchi, lamento diferir, _Javascript_ no hace un ciclo, simplemente "[desempaca los elementos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)" para tratarlos de forma individual.

Comment: Un extra a la respuesta seria que el eperador spread("...") fue incluido desde ES6 por lo que en versiones anteriores no funcionaria. Ademas, es compatible con todos los navegadores

Comment: @Triby ok te lo tomo.. pero eso es lo que dice que hace por arriba.. no dice como hace eso ;)

Comment: @JuanRivera, gracias por la sugerencia, voy a agregarla a la respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Considero que la [respuesta de @Triby](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/443001/16597) es la más acertada ya que explica los errores cometidos y simplifica bastante el código.

Ahora!, otra forma de obtener el resultado es ordenando los número en el arreglo de menor a mayor.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
function menorMayor(numeros) {
  let ordenados = numeros.sort((a, b) => a - b);
  return [ordenados[0], ordenados[numeros.length - 1]];
}

console.log(menorMayor([4, 6, 1, 7, 15]));
```

---

Referencias:

- [`array.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)